# How to connect to display (VGA/Console) of one PC from another as a console?

Tags: linux, usb, console, serial-console

I have an old PC I am trying to configure thru console. Problem is it does not has console or IPMI port.

Instead of hooking a keyboard and monitor to the old PC, I want to connect (somehow) to the "console" of that PC from my regular windows PC or laptop.

target machine:
main board: GA-E7AUM-DS2H  Rev. 1001

Can I use COM port (COMA on right bottom corner) , with a DB9 to USB cable to connect to 'console' of this PC from my laptop? What are my options?

I want to install Linux on it and I am having hard time to figure how to have a console access to this server.

Also, what software should I be using in my PC/laptop to access that USB->COM connection (if I go that route)?

Thank you.

[image: GA-E7AUM-DS2H ver:1.001]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only some motherboards offer serial access to their BIOS (or similar) etc., I don't know this motherboard, but it's a very uncommon feature on boards that weren't made for server use, and given that this appears to have an nvidia gforce chip, I'm guessing it's not made for server use. So you probably wn't have access to anything until an OS has booted.

Some (but not all, and I haven't personally cared about serial access for quite some years, so I have no clue which anymore) offers serial access to their installer. If you use the correct bit rate etc. you should be able to connect to that with a cable as described. I haven't touched windows in years, so I have no idea what you can use there, on Linux I've used minicom (but I don't know if anything else is better these days).

But if it's in anyway possible, I would connect a keyboard+monitor to install Linux (and run through the BIOS to see if there's anything that could be set smarter for the future use), and when it is running and accessible via the network, disconnect those and just access it (via SSH) over the network.

Comment: Thanks for the response Henrik. Actually I am getting errors on OS install (crash) and I want to log that output and share with community to debug/troubleshoot.  For that purpose I need to connect to it as a "console" using some console app (like hyperterminal or minicom).

Comment: "@Henrik supports the community"  Sir, you were right. The COM port on this MOBO does nothing. I got a console server and cisco cable DB9 to RJ45. But it shows nothing.